# Adding padding to NSMutableAttributedString in UITextView

Tags: ios, uitextview

How do I add padding to a substring of `UITextView` that is a `NSMutableAttributedString` (shown here highlighted in yellow)?

[image]

I currently have the attributed text (image 2) without any padding around the attributed text, but need to add some padding to it (image 3), which is some spacing around the highlighted text only (not the entire `UITextView`.

Here is a close-up comparing how the `NSMutableAttributedString` with/without padding (this padding should not apply to the rest of the text which unattributed):

[image]

Here's how I'm currently getting the text from the `UITextView` (after finding the range of text I want to highlight and storing the attributed text in `attributedText`):

```
var highlightedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "this text is highlighted")
let highlightedRange = NSRange(location: 0, length: highlightedText.characters.count)

highlightedText.addAttribute(NSBackgroundColorAttributeName,
                             value: UIColor.yellow, range: highlightedRange)

attributedText.replaceCharacters(in: highlightedRange, with: highlightedText)
```

Comment: give an example

Comment: show us the scenario

Comment: @Fay007 updated

Comment: @user2560886 What do mean by padding here?

Comment: Follow this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231896/how-to-set-margins-padding-in-uitextview

Comment: @SNarula that seems to give padding around the whole `UITextView`, but I only want it around the attributed text?

Comment: @NiravD In the example, the padding add spaces on all sides of the attributed text in yellow (compare image 2 vs image 3), basically [padding like in CSS](http://www.mediaforma.com/uneminuteparjour/html5/images/raccourcissez-vos-styles-css-margin-et-padding-1.jpg)

Comment: In image 3 i don't believe it has extra space in between texts @user2560886

Comment: they are just different font type, change the font family for ur attributed string and u will see the difference

Comment: @Fay007 I added another close-up image, which shows padding around the text

Comment: @Fay007 I need them to be the same size, but with some extra space around it, so the background doesn't hug the text

Comment: @Tj3n Thanks, I've added the example

Comment: Any luck finding a hack?! Or custom attribute is the only way out?

Comment: Any luck yet???

Comment: Sorry, never found out the answer